# QtGridLayout behaving like a QVBoxLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having some issues working with the QGridLayout. Here's the code and the explanation comes after:

```
for(int i =0; i<fileCount; i++)
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    QString DocName = FilteredFiles.at(i).at(0);
    QLabel* DocTitle = new QLabel;
    DocTitle->setText(DocName);
    QLabel* DocIcon = new QLabel;
    if(FilteredFiles.at(i).at(2)== "WORD")
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:blah/blah/blah/WordIcon.jpg");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    else if(FilteredFiles.at(i).at(2)== "EXCEL")
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:/blah/blah/blah/ExcelIcon.png");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    else
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:/blah/blah/blah/PpIcon.png");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    GridContainer->addWidget(DocIcon);
    GridContainer->addWidget(DocTitle);
    TopGrid->addLayout(GridContainer,row,col,1,1);
    col++;
}
MainContainer->addLayout(TopGrid);
```

The above code is supposed to make two Qlabels, pixmap an image to one of the labels, add the pixmapped label and the regular label to a QVBoxLayout and then add the QVBoxLayout to a QGridLayout. The output grid was supposed to have everything on a single row but it's in a column. Can someone explain why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `GridContainer` is a `QVBoxLayout`. You're adding all your widgets into the same layout. That's probably your problem (as well as the problem with your `col` variable being initialized inside your for loop, which was pointed out by user2672165).

You should probably be creating a new `GridContainer` object inside your loop and adding that to your `TopGrid` layout, instead of adding the same layout in your `TopGrid` layout over and over again.

```
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
for(int i =0; i<fileCount; i++)
{
    GridContainer = new QVBoxLayout; // create a new layout
    QString DocName = FilteredFiles.at(i).at(0);
    QLabel* DocTitle = new QLabel;
    DocTitle->setText(DocName);
    QLabel* DocIcon = new QLabel;
    if(FilteredFiles.at(i).at(2)== "WORD")
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:blah/blah/blah/WordIcon.jpg");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    else if(FilteredFiles.at(i).at(2)== "EXCEL")
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:/blah/blah/blah/ExcelIcon.png");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    else
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:/blah/blah/blah/PpIcon.png");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    GridContainer->addWidget(DocIcon);
    GridContainer->addWidget(DocTitle);
    TopGrid->addLayout(GridContainer,row,col,1,1);
    col++;
}
MainContainer->addLayout(TopGrid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move variable col out of loop:

```
int col = 0;
for(int i =0; i<fileCount; i++)
{
    int row = 0;
    QString DocName = FilteredFiles.at(i).at(0);
    QLabel* DocTitle = new QLabel;
    DocTitle->setText(DocName);
    QLabel* DocIcon = new QLabel;
    if(FilteredFiles.at(i).at(2)== "WORD")
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:blah/blah/blah/WordIcon.jpg");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    else if(FilteredFiles.at(i).at(2)== "EXCEL")
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:/blah/blah/blah/ExcelIcon.png");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    else
    {
        QPixmap Icon("C:/blah/blah/blah/PpIcon.png");
        DocIcon->setPixmap(Icon);
    }
    GridContainer->addWidget(DocIcon);
    GridContainer->addWidget(DocTitle);
    TopGrid->addLayout(GridContainer,row,col,1,1);
    col++;
}
MainContainer->addLayout(TopGrid);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. The program remained the same

Comment: Are you sure have re-built and run the correct binary? The correction looks to be effective.

Comment: Yeah I rebuilt the whole thing. Doesn't change anything

Comment: And you have removed the line int col=0; that was within the loop and you are still incrementing col? Then I do not have a clue. I mean I am sure the code you posted have exactly a bug that shows the behavior you describe.